# Using pyparsing to parse a list from a string with special characters

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'd like to parse a list from a string field that may contain special characters such as \ \n \r  \n \t and expand over multiple lines.  Currently, I have to parse the string first, clean it up, then apply the list grammar on the that clean string.  It works ok but just wondering if there's a better way.

This is what I current have

```
str_ = QuotedString('"',escChar='\\',multiline=True)  #grammar for str
str_.setParseAction(lambda pr: pr[0].replace('\\n',' ')\
                        .replace('\\r', ' ')\
                        .replace('\r', ' ')\
                        .replace('\t', ' '))

list_G = delimitedList(Word(printables))('mlist') #grammar for list


def pa(st,locn,pr): return list_G.parseString(pr.mystr)
mylist = Group(str_('mystr').addParseAction(pa)) #read in the str then re-parse
G = Keyword("LIST") + mylist('thelist') + ';'    #grammar for the whole thing
s = 'LIST "one,two,three" ;'
```

Edit: 
Instead of Word(printables) in list_G, changed to

```
var_grammar = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums + "_") #"_a,a2b_,.."
num_grammar = Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")('num')
list_G = delimitedList(var_grammar|num_grammar)('mlist') #grammar for list
G = Keyword("LIST") + '"' + mylist('thelist') + '"' + ';'
```

The reason  that forces me to do the clean up above that replaces `"\\n", "\\r" with ' '`  is because I read in string from a file that literally contains the the charactors `\n, \r` and those are not parsable by var_name or num (they are not printable)

This is an example of a (raw) string in the file :

```
LIST "one,two,
 three,
 \nfour,\rfive";
```

Do you have any suggestion about this ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some special characters in `s`, and show what the problem is if you don't parse in this two-step manner?

Comment: If you actually have the characters of a backslash and an 'n' in the string itself, then define an expression like `unwanted = Word('\\','rnt',exact=2)`, and then do `G.ignore(unwanted)`.

Comment: that seems to be a nice solution -- should be equivalent with current my hack around that replaces those `\t \n \r`  with space right after reading in the file and before parsing it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pyparsing is pretty tolerant of whitespace characters as you show here, so I'm surprised this is an issue.

One problem that you *do* have is in your definition of `list_G`:

```
list_G = delimitedList(Word(printables))('mlist') #grammar for list
```

I get what you're trying to do here, but your list element expression has a key problem. `delimitedList(expr)` is a handy short-cut for `expr + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + expr)`, but the list element expression you are using for `expr` is `Word(printables)`, a word-group of any non-whitespace character. Unfortunately, this includes ',', your list delimiter. When you pass your string "one,two,three" to this expression, `Word(printables)` will parse the whole thing before it ever looks for a delimiter:

```
>>> list_G = delimitedList(Word(printables))
>>> print (list_G.parseString("one,two,three"))
['one,two,three']
```

You need a way to say "I want my word to be everything printable that is not a comma". In older versions of pyparsing, you had to do this yourself with something like:

```
word_of_everything_except_a_comma = Word(''.join(c for c in printables if c != ','))
```

In version 1.5.6, I added an `excludeChars` argument to Word to simplify this. Now you can just write:

```
word_of_everything_except_a_comma = Word(printables, excludeChars=',')
```

With a word like this, you will get a proper 3-element list:

```
>>> list_G = delimitedList(Word(printables, excludeChars=','))
>>> print (list_G.parseString("one,two,three"))
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

This may be the issue you were struggling with, as pyparsing will implicitly skip over the whitespace characters that you are stripping out:

```
>>> s = "one,  two\t\t,\n\n\t\t\t  three"
>>> print (s)
one,  two               ,

                          three
>>> print (list_G.parseString(s))
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: Hi Paul,  I was using the grammars for variables and numbers but decided to use `printables` for the post because it's cleaner (see the edited post). I've edited my orig post that have an example when things don't work.  Hope you can take a look.